# NameError: global name 'totaloverpay' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started college and I am writing this code out for my college class and it keeps sending an error. Any enlightenment will help, maybe the problem is that I'm half asleep.

here is the code

```
def main():
    overtime = int(0)
    totaloverpay = float(0)
    hours = int(input('How many hours did you work? NOTE** Hours can not exceed 86 or be less than 8 '))
    while hours > 86 or hours < 8:
        print('ERROR: Insufficient input. Try again')
        hours = int(input('How many hours did you work? NOTE** Hours can not exceed 86 or be less than 8 '))

    payrate = float(input('What is the payrate per hour for this employee? NOTE** Payrate can not exceed $50.00 or be less than $7.00 '))
    while payrate > 50.00 or payrate < 7.00:
            print('ERROR: Insufficient input. Try again')
            payrate = float(input('What is the payrate per hour for this employee? NOTE** Payrate can not exceed $50.00 or be less than $7.00 '))

    workhours(hours, payrate, overtime)
def workhours(hours, payrate, overtime):
    if hours > 40:
        overtime = (hours - 40) * -1
    else:
        regtime = hours + 0
    paydistribution(hours, payrate, regtime, overtime)
def paydistribution(hours, payrate, regtime, overtime):
    if hours >= 40:
        halfrate = float(payrate * 0.5)
        overpay = halfrate + payrate
        totaloverpay = float(overpay * hours)
    if hours < 40:
        regpay = hours * payrate

    display(hours, payrate, regpay, regtime, overtime)
def display(hours, payrate, regpay, regtime, overtime):
    total = float(regpay + totaloverpay)

    print('     Payroll Information')
    print('Payrate       :', format(payrate, '0.2f'))
    print('Regular Hours :', format(regtime))
    print('Overtime Hours:', format(overtime))
    print('Regular Pay   :', format(regpay, '6.2f'))
    print('Overtime Pay  :', format(totaloverpay, '7.2f'))
    print('Total Pay     :', format(total, '7.2f'))

main()
```

Comment: In the future, if you're getting an error when you run your code, please include the error message in your post. It will make the problem much faster and easier to pin down if we don't have to dig through your code for anything that looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

totaloverplay is not defined in any function below main in which it is referred to, or as a global variable. If you want it to be global, define it outside of the main function's scope.

Comment: *If you want it to be global, define it outside of the main function's scope.* Note: additional changes would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should not get in the habit of using `global`; it's usually a sign that you're heading in the wrong direction. Instead, pass the variables you need around explicitly, using function arguments and return statements. Also, don't pass functions arguments they don't need to do their job, and prefer default arguments or explicit constants to "magic numbers". For example:

```
def workhours(hours, threshold=40):
    if hours > threshold:
        overtime = hours - threshold
        regtime = threshold
    else:
        overtime = 0
        regtime = hours
    return regtime, overtime

def paydistribution(payrate, regtime, overtime, otrate=1.5):
    regpay = regtime * payrate
    overpay = overtime * payrate * otrate
    return regpay, overpay
```

Now `main` can call:

```
regtime, overtime = workhours(hours)
regpay, overpay = paydistribution(payrate, regtime, overtime)
display(hours, payrate, regpay, regtime, overtime)
```

This keeps the flow mostly in `main` while letting the other functions do just their specific bits of the task.

In your position, I would also consider having a separate function to take user input, which loops until they provide something acceptable. An appropriate definition, for example:

```
def user_input(prompt, min_, max_):
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a great use-case for a `class` rather than relying on functional programming.

```
from decimal import Decimal # more precision than floating point

MINIMUM_WAGE = Decimal("7.25")
OVERTIME_RATE = Decimal("1.5")

class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self,first,last,MI="",payrate=MINIMUM_WAGE):
        self.first = first.capitalize()
        self.last = last.capitalize()
        self.MI = MI.upper()
        if not MI.endswith("."): self.MI += "."
        self.payrate = payrate
        self.hours = 0
    @property
    def name(self, reversed_=False):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.first,self.MI,self.last)
    @property
    def alphabetize(self):
        return "{}, {}".format(self.last, self.first)

    def payroll(self,numweeks=1):
        regularhours = min(40*numweeks,self.hours)
        OThours = max(0,self.hours-regularhours)
        regularpay = regularhours * self.payrate
        OTpay = round(OThours * self.payrate * OVERTIME_RATE,2)
        return {"reghours":regularhours,
                "overtime":OThours,
                "regpay":regularpay,
                "OTpay":OTpay,
                "total":regularpay + OTpay}

    def sethoursworked(self,amt):
        self.hours = amt

def display(employee):
    payrollinfo = employee.payroll()
    print("{:^30}".format("Payroll Information"))
    print("{:>30}".format(employee.name))
    print("Payrate:{:>22}".format(employee.payrate))
    print("Hours:{:>24}".format(payrollinfo['reghours']))
    print("Overtime Hours:{:>15}".format(payrollinfo['overtime']))
    print("Regular Pay:{:>18}".format(payrollinfo['regpay']))
    print("Overtime Pay:{:>17}".format(payrollinfo['OTpay']))
    print("-"*30)
    print("Total Pay:{:>20}".format(payrollinfo['total']))

Adam = Employee("Adam","Smith","D")
Adam.sethoursworked(51)

display(Adam)
```

> OUTPUT:

```
     Payroll Information      
                 Adam D. Smith
Payrate:                  7.25
Hours:                      40
Overtime Hours:             11
Regular Pay:            290.00
Overtime Pay:           119.62
------------------------------
Total Pay:              409.62
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another cleaned-up version:

```
from textwrap import dedent
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input

MIN_HOURS = 8.
MAX_HOURS = 86.
MIN_RATE  = 7.
MAX_RATE  = 50.
OVERTIME_CUTOFF = 40.
OVERTIME_BONUS  = 0.5

def get_float(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            val = float(inp(prompt))
            if lo is not None and val < lo:
                print("Value must be >= {}".format(lo))
            elif hi is not None and val > hi:
                print("Value must be <= {}".format(hi))
            else:
                return val
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number")

def main():
    hours = get_float("How many hours did you work? ", MIN_HOURS, MAX_HOURS)
    rate  = get_float("What is the hourly payrate? ",  MIN_RATE,  MAX_RATE)

    time     = min(hours, OVERTIME_CUTOFF)
    pay      = time * rate
    overtime = max(0., hours - OVERTIME_CUTOFF)
    overpay  = overtime * rate * (1. + OVERTIME_BONUS)

    print(dedent("""
            Payroll Information
        Payrate       : $ {rate:>7.2f}
        Regular Hours :   {time:>4.0f} h
        Regular Pay   : $ {pay:>7.2f}
        Overtime Hours:   {overtime:>4.0f} h
        Overtime Pay  : $ {overpay:>7.2f}
        Total Pay     : $ {total:>7.2f}
    """).format(rate=rate, time=time, pay=pay, overtime=overtime, overpay=overpay, total=pay+overpay))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
How many hours did you work? 46
What is the hourly payrate? 11

    Payroll Information
Payrate       : $   11.00
Regular Hours :     40 h
Regular Pay   : $  440.00
Overtime Hours:      6 h
Overtime Pay  : $   99.00
Total Pay     : $  539.00
```